# Исправить ошибки в тексте, отображающемся во время технических работ

Tags: дефект, статус-проверка, локализация, нет-в-transifex, технические-работы

Во время технических работ я зашёл по адресу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ и увидел надпись:

> Обычно, техническое обслуживание длиться менее часа.

> [image: Скриншот ошибки]

В ней лишний мягкий знак в слове "длится". Также я сомневаюсь в запятой после "Обычно", скорее всего, она не нужна.

Надо исправить первое предложение так:

> Обычно техническое обслуживание длится менее часа.

---

Дополнительно было бы неплохо перевести и заголовок страницы. Сейчас это "We are Offline".

И ещё стоит добавить кавычки-ёлочки вокруг имени сайта:

> «Stack Overflow на русском» отключён ...

Comment: Что-то не могу эту строку в традусёре найти 

Comment: @Suvitruf Это значит, что уже поправили? Я думаю, может быть, что эта надпись не всё время висела, или это что-то в духе первоапрельских изменений дизайна и оттуда, например, или просто в каком-то странном месте находится?

Comment: Скорей всего, это какой-т хардкод. Но подождём нашего робота, может он чего подскажет.

Comment: @Suvitruf, хардкод на русском? Как-то вряд ли.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik есть новости? Вчерашний оффлайн опять испортил настроение этой надписью)

Comment: @andreymal нету такой строки. А это точно текстом было, а не картинкой?

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik точно https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGAy7.png

Comment: Кстати, может ещё стоит заменить "детали" на "подробности"? А то ощущается как калька с английского details

Comment: И до кучи "отключён" через "ё" должно быть.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov [посмотрим, что скажут эксперты](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/474332/183872)