# Грамматическая ошибка

Tags: дефект

Только что пробовал зайти, но увидел следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Техническое обслуживание *что делает*? Значит, надо писать *длится*, без мягкого знака.

И запятая после "Обычно" тоже не нужна.

Это все, что я хотел написать.

P.S. Какой смысл объявлять вопрос дублем, если ответа на него - исправления ошибки - нет уже много лет? Не проще ли исправить ошибку?

Comment: ЕМНИП эта ошибка уже несколько лет))) и даже темы были про это))   https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11676/191482  в 2021 и  https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9392/191482 - 2019  :DDDD

Comment: Только разработчики могут исправить...

Comment: @Qwertiy А кто им должен сообщить?